# Use subquery result in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
select distinct (`hostname`)  as  h from `drpl_comment` c where 
(select count(cid) from  `drpl_comment` where  hostname == h ) > 0
```

My intention is to get all hostnames from the drpl_comment table if the hostname value has more than one occurrence in the table.

Could you help me build this query?

Comment: What exactly is now the problem (except the == in the query which is wrong)? edit: question was edited :-)

Answer (score 3):

you can simply do it using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT  hostname
FROM    drpl_comment
GROUP   BY hostName
HAVING  COUNT(cid) > 0
```

Comment: Nice solution - one thing to note is he stated "has more than one occurrence in the table" - so i'm not sure if there is a typo in his code or in his description, if it truly is more than one occurrence it should be > 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT `hostname` AS h, COUNT(`hostname`) AS count_h 
FROM `drpl_comment`
GROUP BY `hostname`
HAVING count_h > 2
```

`GROUP BY ... HAVING` solve exactly this problem :)

### Update:

As mentioned by ***J    W***, the use of `DISTINCT` doesn't affect the results of the query in this context. So it can be removed from the query.

Comment: when grouping with `hostname`, the result of `hostname` is always unique.